# Cron runs script but code doesn't execute

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a cronjob that looks like this:

```
30-59/1 13 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/php /home/myproject/main/logic.php 2>&1 >>/home/myproject/main/cronlog.txt
```

I can run the script fine from the command line.

And I can see it being ran in syslog.

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog

Apr  5 18:51:01 ip-x-x-x-x CRON[30277]: (ubuntu) CMD (/usr/bin/php /home/myproject/main/logic.php 2>&1 /home/myproject/main/cronlog.txt)
```

Permissions:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 4791 Apr  5 18:31 logic.php
```

In my php file:

```
require '/home/myproject/main/data.php';
require '/home/myproject/vendor/autoload.php';
```

But the code in my script is not actually executing.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: I'm sending stderr to a text file but it's empty. Any specific log I should check?

Answer (score 2):

You sending stderr to stdout, but your not sending stdout anywhere. Need to put the > in front of your file.

```
30-59/1 13 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/php /home/myproject/main/logic.php 2>&1 >/home/myproject/main/cronlog.txt
```